# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Fluent::after()

Tags: php, laravel

I have been trying to run php artisan migrate but always gives this error

this is my migration:
`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class AlterTableRhRacaCorAddCodEsocial extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('rh_raca_cor', function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->unsignedInteger('cod_esocial')->after('cod');
        });

        DB::statement("update rh_raca_cor set cod_esocial = case 
            when id = 1 then 4
            when id = 2 then 1
            when id = 3 then 5
            when id = 4 then 3
            when id = 5 then 2
            else 6 end;
        ");
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('rh_raca_cor', function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->dropColumn('cod_esocial');
        });
    }
}
```

`

Been trying to find this same error when I search but unfortnatelly unable to solve it.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you running?

Comment: Version 5.3 Laravel

Comment: Is this a MySQL database?

Comment: It's mariaDB...

Comment: Comparing your code to [the first example migration in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#migration-structure), you are missing `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I was facing was related to the composer version that I had installed, it was the latest but had to go back to version 1.10.17

```
composer self-update 1.10.17;
```